# RDS: Redirected printers not showing up in Control Panel or Settings app

Tags: remote-desktop, printing, remote-desktop-services, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I'm having an odd problem with our *Remote Desktop Session Host* that's running on *Windows Server 2019* (version 1809, build 17763.805). I am connecting to this server from my PC (running *Windows 10*, version 1903, build 18362.418) using *mstsc.exe* (shell/control version 10.0.18362).

I have a bunch of printers on my computer, and I have selected in mstsc.exe to redirect all printers. This is a screenshot of the *Devices and Printers* control panel on my PC:

[image: Devices and Printers on PC]

However, when looking in the corresponding control panel on the *Remote Desktop Session Host*, I don't see my redirected printers:

[image: Devices and Printers on Remote Desktop Session Host]

They also don't show up in the new *Settings* app on the Remote Desktop Session Host:

[image: Settings App on Remote Desktop Session Host]

Even though the printers are not showing up in *Devices and Printers* or the *Settings* app, the printers are available to programs within the Remote Desktop Session Host, and do show up in Print Management.

[image: Notepad print dialog on Remote Desktop Session Host]

[image: Print Management on Remote Desktop Session Host]

This problem has occured for us with multiple Windows Server 2019 servers in different environments, and has occurred with multiple client operating systems as well. We've of course tried rebooting the affected machines, this has not cleared anything up.

The machine I'm connecting from also does not have a long hostname. There is an issue going around from research where machines that have 15 character long hostnames can have this issue, that is however not the case for my test machine. Neither the client or the host machine has a hostname longer than 9 characters.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, redirected printers aren't listed in Settings or in Control panel. Only "locally" installed printers are.

If the printers are being redirected successfully, as they seem to be, what's the actual problem... other than their not being listed in Settings and Control Panel?

Comment: They have been listed in Settings and Control Panel in earlier versions of Windows. The users need to be able to change printer settings and set default printers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fix for the problem, but a workaround.  It appears that if you open the CLSID for Printers, the redirected printers are displayed.

Execute the following from the Start menu, or Start->Run dialog

```
explorer shell:::{863aa9fd-42df-457b-8e4d-0de1b8015c60}
```

or

```
explorer shell:::{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}
```

I was able to create a shortcut that would open the Printers folder with all printers.

[image]

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465552/open-devices-and-printers-window-in-batch

Also https://www.eightforums.com/threads/clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-for-windows-8.13591/

Answer (score 0):

We have the same error on our 2012R2 RDS Farm , have read a lot of blogs but none of the sugestions seem to be working , we still want to test the one where it advises that you need to shorten the hostname of the pc , a temoprary workaround that we want to implement is creating a registry entry to dispay printers on the desktop as per the below link.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c430c930-286a-4e61-822f-a7e56d90fd8d/redirected-printers-not-showing-in-devices-and-printer-unable-to-change-defaults?forum=winserverTS

Comment: Hi, please add detail, as link only answer is not good, and Technet forums are getting migrated, as such the info can be lost with times.

Answer (score 0):

Check how long the local computer's name is.  If it's 15+ characters long, you'll see this exact issue.  Shorten it, and you should see the printers show up in control panel etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion, but this was already adressed in the last paragraph of my question. In this case, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this registry and it worked for me

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Device Metadata\PreventDeviceMetadataFromNetwork

change dword from 0 to 1

reboot the system